# VB.NET How to paint and deal with infinite canvas

Tags: vb.net, canvas, resize, zooming, paint

i read a lot of simple-drawing examples or advanced examples with open and save image, but i do not found a good tutorial or - may be i didn't found the right search words - howto to build a infinite canvas.

i'm not sure that i use the right terms for searching.

what i want to do is to write a program where i draw a lot of objects (self-drawing) on the canvas. [check ;-)]
if i scroll maybe to the left, the canvas hast do grow, the same to the all other directions.
if the user zooms out, the canvas become bigger on all sides.

for example, ms visio, there is the blank page, but i can always move the objects out of it.

did you know what i mean?

regards
lw

Comment: maybe a Panel with AutoScroll on?

Comment: if so, how would i start? i have no idea for using the panel (i know the panel but not in this way)